# Hudson Continuous Integration Server with .Net 1.1

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, hudson, msbee

Has anyone successfully used hudson to build .Net 1.1 Projects? If so, can you share the configuration. I am having trouble.

Hudson uses MSBuild which was introduced with .Net 2.0. I found **[MSBee](http://www.codeplex.com/MSBee)** which is a MSBuild toolkit for 1.1 but so far I have not got it to work with Hudson. I point Hudson at the 2.0 MSbuild after installing MSBee and have tried the following arguments (among other things)

```
/t:Rebuild /p:TargetFX1_1=true 

/p:TargetFX1_1=true /p:CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets=D\SCM\MSBuild\MSBee\MSBuildExtras.Fx1_1.CSharp.targets
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using NAnt for 1.1 projects, which was simpler to integrate for me than MSBuild. You have a hudson [plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/NAnt+Plugin) for it.